# Show that all homomorphsms phi are of the same form (problem)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

***Problem:***
Let $p$ be an odd prime.  Let $G = Z_p \times Z_p$.
a group under addition.  (Ignore multiplication in this problem.)
Let $a,b,c,d\in Z_p$ and define $\phi: G\rightarrow G$ by

$\phi((i,j)) = (ai+bj, ci+dj)$

a) Show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

b) Show that all homomorphisms $\psi:Z_p\rightarrow Z_p$
are of this form.  (Idea: $\psi$ is determined by $\psi((1,0))$
and $\psi((0,1))$.)

c) Show that, with $\phi$ given by (1), $\phi$ is an
isomorphism if and only if $ad-bc=0$ in $Z_p$.

***Attempt:***

a) I got this one, I just showed that products go to products for a homomorphism.

b) I don't think I understand this question. I thought anything that sends $Z_p$ to $Z_p$ would be a homomorphism of one element $z\in$$Z_p$ not a combination such as (1,0) or (0,1). What exactly is this asking?

c) I feel like if I understand b I'll be able to get this one myself.

Comment: @David : How is $\psi$ defined? Is it a map from $Z_p \times Z_p \to Z_p \times Z_p $ or $ Z_p \to Z_p $?

Comment: @David : Is (a) clear?

Comment: @Manasi: Yeah for (a) I just proved that $\phi((i+k,j+l))=\phi((i,j))+\phi((k,l))$.

Comment: @ David : Okay, do you mean $\phi ((i+k, j+l)) = \phi((i,j)) + \phi((k,l))$.

Comment: @ Manasi, yeah that's right, thank you for pointing it out, I updated it in my comment.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Sorry, I had not addressed the comment to you. The map has to be well-defined.

Comment: Good. Now please read my comment about $\psi$ above.

Comment: @Manasi, it states it as a map from $Z_p$$\rightarrow$$Z_p$

Comment: For part b) you get that all the homomorphisms are of that form since $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: .. but you are talking about $\psi((1,0)$ and $\psi(0,1)$. Its clear that the domain of the map is $Z_p \times Z_p$.

Comment: @Manasi Nice observation... :D forget about "well" defined.. it is not at all "defined" :P :P

Comment: Nevermind, I understand it now. As a notation thing, what exactly does (1) mean in part c?

Comment: It means $\phi$ is a homomorphism and it is bijective i.e every element of $Z_p \times Z_p$ is mapped to a corresponding element of $Z_p \times Z_p$. Each element in the range has been mapped to by some element in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $\phi(1,0)=(a,c)$ and $\phi(0,1)=(b,d)$.